# how can i stop scrolling and resume scrolling when click on button?

Tags: jquery, scroll

how can I stop scrolling  with jquery when the scrolling  reach certain section or block on my page?

and how can I  resume the scroll when I click on button or link  on that section ?

and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using mousewheel

```
$('body').on({
    'mousewheel': function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'domid') return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```